# Publish button doesn't do anything (django forms)

Tags: python, django

I am following an online django course and one of the exercises includes creating a blog. One of the elements of the blog includes a *"Publish"* button but when I click it nothing happens.

This is the code:

*HTML:*

```
<a class = "btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_publish' pk=post.pk %}">Publish</a>
```

*views.py:*

```
@login_required
def post_publish(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
    post.publish()
    return redirect('post_detail',pk=pk)
```

*urls.py:*

```
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/publish/$',views.post_publish,name='post_publish'),
```

Comment: Do you have a function named publish? What does it do? Are you using wagtail for pages or another CMS? What's your expected outcome vs what's happening?

Comment: I'm a beginner so I'm not sure I understand all your questions. But will try my best. I created a function-view called post-publish. That view is called by the html code. Both of those pieces of code are what I've pasted here. Also I'm just using atom editor and cmdline to create django projects.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: check what you button/link element actually has proper url

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have added the below detail in your settings file. If yes, then skip this part.

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],  # Add this to your settings file
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

myproject/
 |-- myproject/
 |    |-- myapp/
 |    |-- myproject/
 |    |-- templates/     <-- here!
 |    |    |-- myapp/
 |    |    |    |-- index.html
 |    |    |-- base.html
 |    |    +-- home.html
 |    +-- manage.py
 +-- venv/
```

**views.py:**

```
@login_required
def post_publish(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
    return render(request, template_name.html,{'post': post})
```

Try using return render this will work for sure.
In your view you have not show anywhere. what is your template_name.

Answer (score -1):

From Django Docs:

Additional form template furniture

Don’t forget that a form’s output does not include the surrounding  tags, or the form’s submit control. You will have to provide these yourself.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/

You are missing the input with type submit:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

After handling the submitted data in your views.py you can redirect to the desired url there is no need to use an  tag.

Comment: Quick update and quasi-fix: After several attempts at debugging, someone recommended that I clear my browser's cache. That finally fixed it. But now I am not sure which bug exactly prevented the Publish button from working in the first place. My code still does not have the "input type = submit". I am going to go through all my code one time and will update here if I figure it out.